# Iterating through multiple API payloads

Tags: python, api, payload

**Background:**

1. I have a dictionary `my_dict` containing c.3000 rows of key/value pairs - 
   **Extract:**
   `{'id_and_external_id_sf': {11028697: '0013h000014kIGMAA2', 11028699: '0013h000014kISXAA2', 10264791: '0013h00000ZBqoYAAT'}}`
2. I also have a payload, stored in `data`, which I will need to inc. in API calls for each key/pair value in `my_dict`
    Specifically, I need to iterate through `my_dict` and for every key/pair value, need to map `id` and `external_id_sf` to their respective places in the payload.
    **Payload:**

```
    data =  """
        {
       "data": {
          "id": "<KEY FROM DICT>",
          "type": "entities",
          "attributes": {
             "external_id_sf": "<VALUE FROM DICT>"
          }
       }
    }
    """
```

3. Finally, when calling the API, the `PATCH` url needs to be suffixed with the `id` from `my_dict`. E.g., the payload that contains `11028697: '0013h000014kIGMAA2'` will have a URL of `https://myfirm.vendor.com/api/v1/entities/11028697`

**My code so far:**

Function that saves key-value pairs in `my_dict` from .xlsx file:

```
    # Saving key-value pairs from a .xlsx file
    def excel_to_dict():
        my_dict = pd.read_excel('entities.xlsx', index_col=0).to_dict()
        return my_dict
    excel_to_dict()
```

Function that saves all `id` from .xlsx file to list, so API urls can be constructed:

```
def ids_list():
    df = pd.read_excel('entities.xlsx')
    ids_list = df['entities'].tolist()
    return ids_list
```

Function that creates API `PATCH` call URLs, using `id`s from `ids_list()`

```
def url_constructor():
    ids_list = excel_to_list()
    str = "https://firm.vendor.com/api/v1/entities/{}"
    url_list = []
    for entity in ids_list:
        url = str.format(entity)
        url_list.append(url)
    return url_list
url_constructor()
```

Function that contains payload (`data`) template, which needs to be inc. in the API calls for each respective `id` and `external_id_sf`:

```
def payload_data():
    data =  """
        {
       "data": {
          "id": "11028697",
          "type": "entities",
          "attributes": {
             "external_id_sf": "0013h000014kIGMAA2"
          }
       }
    }
    """
    return data
```

**Where I need help:**
 I am struggling to work out how I can bring these segments of code together so I can the following is achieved -

1. Make an API call for each url in `url_list`
2. Whilst calling a url, inc. the payload with the same `id` and it's corresponding `external_id_sf` from `my_dict`, to ensure the correct payload is sent for each API call. I'm not sure if you can use curly brackets, for the purpose of data mapping, as I did in the `url_constructor` function.

I appreciate this is a lot of information, so any suggestions would be warmly received.

Comment: For the payload data, define it as a dict, you can use something like `requests.patch(url, json=payload_data())`

Comment: @Peter - thanks for your response. My big issue is determining how to iterate through the `dict` and create unique payloads, that map each key (`id`) and value (`external_id_sf`) pairs to the respective places in the payload.

Comment: That part I didn't understand too well. Perhaps have the arguments like `payload_data(id, external_id_sf)` to build the payload, and construct the URL + payload together rather than constructing the URL list separately.